# Windows thread sleep and wake from another thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a thread running in a class that I would like to send itself to sleep and wake up  when another thread wakes it up, without passing a mutex or another element around if possible, so it's self contained.

Basically, I have tried the approach of a mutex in the thread that calls WaitForSingleObject twice, expecting it to make the mutex non signaling the first call, but each time the functions return 0 because the mutex is already signaled and the thread is the mutex owner and remains the owner. I expected that once asleep, a class method be called to release the mutex, for example.

Is there an easy approach to this in Windows or will I be forced to break encapsulation? run

Comment: A mutex is not the right synchronization primitive for this situation.  Firstly, as you've already noted, a mutex is reentrant, so you can't wait on a mutex you already own; secondly, even if you could, you'd wind up stuck because only the thread that owns the mutex can release it.  An event object would work, because it can be signaled by any thread.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I ended up using a combination of Suspend/Resume for one thread, with Events to wake another. Seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the Waitable handle approach is the generally favoured way to approach this task, you can always use SuspendThread / ResumeThread to do what you're trying to do without using WaitForSingleObject / WaitForMultipleObjects.

Both functions take a handle to the thread you want to sleep or wake.

Comment: Can the thread itself do it and another thread come by and wake it up with this approach?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: Yes. SuspendThread(GetCurrentThread()). Anyone with a handle to the thread (via OpenThread(int pid)) can then call ResumeThread on that handle to wake it up.

Comment: 'Although the Mutex approach is the generally favoured way to approach this task' - no, not really.  Events/semaphores, usually!